# Adding rows and applying it to a data frame in R

Tags: r, function, seq, rep

I have a df:

```
Q1_3  Q2_3  Q3_3  Q4_3  Q5_3 ...  
16.01  8.23 18.13 11.14 18.03 ...  
17.25  7.50 11.72 10.84  7.24 ...  
3.08  2.12  4.39  3.16  2.44 ...    
4.94  3.95  6.87  3.75  4.10 ...  
3.89  8.35  7.80  2.90  2.55 ...
```

I'd like to create a function that sequentially adds the df[1:5], [6:10] etc. and applies this to the whole data frame.

```
fun1<- function(x) c(x[1] + x[2], x[3] + x[4], x[5] + x[6], x[7] + x[8], x[9] + x[10], x[11] + x[12], x[13] + x[14])
```

I used this one to do another one that I need, however I think there should be a way to use seq() or rep() and apply it to the whole df.

```
testfun<- function(x) c(rowSums(x[1:5]))
```

this adds up the columns that I need, however I cannot figure out how to sequence it for the whole df. I would appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop over the sequence (`seq(1, ncol(df1), by =5)`) ,  create the index (`i:(i+4)`), subset the dataset, do the `rowSums` and then `cbind` with the original dataset.

```
cbind(df1, sapply(seq(1, ncol(df1), by=5), function(i)
                rowSums(df1[i:pmin((i+4), ncol(df1))], na.rm=TRUE)))
```

If we need a function

```
f1 <- function(dat, n=5){
       cbind(dat, sapply(seq(1, ncol(dat), by = n), function(i)
             rowSums(dat[i:pmin((i+(n-1)), ncol(dat))], 
               na.rm=TRUE)))
       }
f1(df1)
```

Comment: I think this one works well! I just need to put it into a function so I can apply it to other data frames as well! Thanks a lot

Comment: @CsabaSzabo  It is easy to create a function based on this.  I will update

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun, that saves my life! What do I need to add to the function to subset only the result in the output without replicating the previous variables?

Comment: @CsabaSzabo If you don't need the original dataset, just remove the `cbind(dat,` in the function.

Comment: Just to express my gratitude again: This function solves my first command as well as if we change n=5 to n=2, it adds x[1:2], x[3:4] so on! I just thought I add it to say thank you and I am sure it will help other readers as well! :) @akrun

Answer (score 1):

```
 n <- 5
 g <- as.numeric(gl(ncol(df1), n, ncol(df1)))
 e2 <- t(aggregate(t(as.matrix(df1))~ g, FUN=sum)[,-1])
 cbind(df1, e2)
```

1. construct a factor to group the columns.
2. aggregate the transposed dataframe
3. `cbind()`

and a little bit shorter:

```
n <- 5
g <- as.numeric(gl(ncol(df1), n, ncol(df1)))
e2 <- aggregate(t(df1)~ g, FUN=sum)
cbind(df1, t(e2[-1]))
```

as function:

```
f <- function(df, n=5) {
    g <- as.numeric(gl(ncol(df), n, ncol(df)))
    aggregate(t(df)~ g, FUN=sum)
}
cbind(df1, t(f(df1)[-1]))
```

Comment: I am not sure what this one returns tbh as I have the same ncol as the original df, however not sure what variables are in them... I should have ncol/5 in the output as every 5th column is added up...

Comment: I constructed another solution which gives the desired result.

Comment: e2 == f1(df) returns all true! :)) thanks a lot @jogo, this works as well :)

Comment: I guess just `as.numeric(gl(ncol(df1), 5, ncol(df1)))` should work.  (not tested)

Comment: that creates unused levels (but works ... and the code is shorter). `as.numeric()` is not needed for only grouping. I tested my code.

Comment: I wrapped `as.numeric` to avoid the `unused level` problem

Comment: I used your idea in a new version, now with variable `n`